# Loader not being shown on ajax request in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Since I am using ajax request using $http. It takes a long time since my operation on server takes time. I need to show loader while processing request, but the loader does not show. Although my code seems correct. I tried different methods but did not work.

**Index.html**

```
<body ng-app="app">

    <!-- loader, can be used on multiple pages-->
    <div class="loading loader-quart" ng-show="isLoading"></div>

<!--         my logic       --> 

</body>
```

**addCtrl.js**

```
//method to get all the attributes and send to server using service
    $scope.add = function () {
        if ($scope.Option == 'newInstance')
            $scope.singleObject.FK_Name = 'MetisEmptyTemplate';
        $rootScope.isLoading = true;
        var featuresList = websiteService.getUpdatedTree($scope.treeDataSource);
        var formData = new Website("", $scope.singleObject.Name, $scope.singleObject.DisplayName, $scope.singleObject.Description, $scope.singleObject.State, "", $scope.singleObject.FK_Name, $scope.singleObject.Email, featuresList);

        websiteService.addwebsite(formData);
        $rootScope.isLoading = false;
    }
```

**websiteService.js**

```
//service to add website
    this.addwebsite = function (website) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: $rootScope.url + 'Add',
            data: JSON.stringify(website),
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //alert(data);
        });
    }
```

Since I am going to turn isLoading as "true" in start and then after request completes I turn isLoading "false". Where is the problem in code?

Comment: You set it on the `$rootScope`, so you need to do: `ng-show="$root.isLoading"`

Comment: But that also does not work. Since rootscope can access everything within app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your websiteServices code gets executed asynchronously. Which means that the above code would display the loader and then pretty much hide it again instantly.

To handle async code in the controller you must return a promise from the service and put the hiding of the spinner in a callback function using `.then()`.

service:

```
this.addwebsite = function (website) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: $rootScope.url + 'Add',
        data: JSON.stringify(website),
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert(data);
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        //alert(data);
        deferred.reject(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise
}
```

controller:

```
websiteService.addwebsite(formData).then(function(){
    $rootScope.isLoading = false
});
```

Comment: do i need to include dependency of $q ?

Comment: Yes in your service you must inject `$q`. Its built in to angular so just inject it

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question, for more information about angulars promise implementation see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Hey loader is working but i ran to a problem 

Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at 
`websiteService.addwebsite(formData)`

Comment: Seems like you're not returning the promise correctly from the service then.

Comment: yes i missed `return deferred.promise`
Thank you legend!

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.insertMliveResponse = function(data){
        var defer=$q.defer();
        var requestURL='/mlive-portlet/rest/mliveResponseService/insertmLiveResponse';
        httpRequest(requestURL,data).then(function(data){
                defer.resolve(data.data);
        },function(data){
            defer.reject(data.data);
        })
        return defer.promise;
    }
```

Comment: try to  use defer.promise

Comment: why do i need to return defer.Promise?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making request then, 
I think the best way to `show` `hide` loader is `interceptor`

In my snippet, I am using loader service to activate/deactivate loader

**For Eg:**

```
// http.config.js  file
export function httpConfig($httpProvider, AuthInterceptProvider) {
  'ngInject';
  AuthInterceptProvider.interceptAuth(true);

  // added for show loader
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function (loaderService, $q) {
    'ngInject';
    return {
      'request': function (config) {
        loaderService.switchLoaderModeOn();
        return config;
      },

      'requestError': function (rejection) {
        loaderService.switchLoaderModeOff();
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      },

      'response': function (response) {
        loaderService.switchLoaderModeOff();
        return response;
      },

      'responseError': function (rejection) {
        loaderService.switchLoaderModeOff();
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    };
  });
}

// and in your module.js file
import {httpConfig} from './config/http.config';

.config(httpConfig)
```